# Hibernate connect to a MySQL Cluster

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, cluster-computing

I am trying to connect to a MySQL cluster using Hibernate from a Tomcat/Spring application. My database connection string is:

**jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://host-1,host-2/database?loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=5000**, where host-1 is **like 10.xx.xx.xxx:3306**.

The schema is always created just on host-2 with the **InnoDB** storage engine, instead of **NDBCLUSTER**.

I am using Hibernate 4.3.7. My MySQL JDBC driver is of 5.1.34 version.

The MySQL cluster is active-active type.